# How to achieve a smooth slide in transition in Premiere?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, adobe, transitions, premiere-pro

I'm a beginner in video editing and I would like to apply a similar transition to my project. Do you have any suggestions on how to do it in the best way?

I have tried to use After Effects but I am not sure which program will do better.

[image: here's the transition]

Answer (score 0):

[image: animation example]
(The animation above is at 15fps to reduce file size, so won't playback smoothly).

The example you've shown looks as though it might be from a web page, in which case it might have been made using CSS animations.

If you want to make something similar using After Effects, you can animate it like this:

Make a layer of text, centre it on the screen.

Right click on the position control on the text layer and check "Separate Dimensions".  This makes it easier to only animate the horizontal (x-axis) position of your text, especially when working with Curves (see below).

Animate your position keyframe, so that it begins off-screen, then comes into your original position.  Add another keyframe to hold it there for a few seconds, then animate it off the other side.

With the X position control selected, click on the Curves button
[image]

You should be able to adjust the curve of the x-position so that it forms nice "S" shapes.  This will make the text slow down as it enters and leaves in a smoother more natural way.  See [easing](https://lesterbanks.com/2016/04/2-tips-super-smooth-eases-effects/) for more info.

Click the Curves button again to turn off the Curves view.

Now go into the Text controller and click on the "Animate" button
[image]

Choose Tracking.

Go to the beginning of your timeline.

Set the tracking type to "Before", and keyframe it.

Set the tracking amount to 45 and keyframe it.

Move along your timeline until the text is in view.

Set another keyframe to adjust the tracking to zero.

Move along your timeline to where your next Position keyframe is.

Set another "Tracking" keyframe (at zero), and set the Tracking Type to "After".

Move along your timeline until the text has moved off-screen, and set another tracking keyframe to "45".

Now click on the Tracking Amount control and click the Curves button again.

Again, make the curves look like nice S shapes:
[image]

Turn off the Curves view, and tweak the positions of all the keyframes until it looks right.